# In ruby insert a row in existing excel sheet with same formula & formatting as previous row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel

I have an excel file with a rows having some formulas and formatting. Is it possible to insert a new row with same formulas and formatting as previous row & allow downloading this file.

I tried using rubyXL, it allows parsing an existing file & adding new rows, but it doesn't add new row with same data, formula and formatting as previous row.

Can anybody suggest a good ruby gem to support this feature.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Have you tried axlsx gem for this?